# How do I get JavaScript and Python to communicate continuously via Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, frontend, backend

I am very new to JavaScript, Python, and web development, but I am trying to create a webpage that takes in data whenever a key is pressed and sends it to a python back end for processing. The Python back end will then send information back to the JavaScript page, and the JavaScript page will respond to it. This process needs to happen continuously, or until it is terminated by a certain response from the Python portion. I already have a script written that gathers all of the data I need on the Javascript end, and I have a Python application that processes it (it needs a little editing to take in one array at a time, but that is not the question). Currently, my trouble has centered around getting them to communicate. I am using Flask as this is in the early stages of development, and I've read it makes for an easy and efficient tool.

I started by trying to follow tutorials on how to get the thing up and running, without too much success. All of the tutorials I've found online are centered around an example, leaving me rather confused about the general. The code I am showing below is what I have to work with from one of the tutorials. I know that render_template opens up the file given (in this case index.html). My first question is: would I put the JavaScript portion as a script within that index file? I've read that logic should generally be kept out of the templates, but I'm not sure how else I'd run this script- it is supposed to run continually underneath what the user is doing on the website. Some other tutorials have indicated that perhaps the answer is to use multiple @app.route statements, but I am not even certain what @app.route is doing exactly. I know it is a decorator, but for what function and what it is changing it to eludes me even after basic research. What does @app.route do? Another tutorial I followed gave me something like what is shown below, but I'm a little confused as to what each @app.route is doing. I'm also not sure what request.get_json() is. From what I have read, JSON is a way of describing data by its attributes rather than including all of the data itself, but I'm not sure what request does (I know it was imported from flask).

From here, the JavaScript needs to have a post function, right? I am assuming that Python would "get" what JavaScript "posted", but the second tutorial's code seems to indicate otherwise (as the function that requests the data (I assume) via request.get_json() is also listed as methods = ['POST']). I am also assuming that I am able to run a 'POST' request on the front-end as part of a function that responds to an Event Listener (on keypress). After Python gets what JavaScript posted Python would post a response and JavaScript would get that and respond to it in kind. I am assuming that is how that all works.

Finally, does someone have an explanation or resource on how JavaScript posts or gets requests? I have some resources I can try, but I haven't had much time to fully explore them yet. I have included in the code section what I have tried so far.

In summary, I feel a bit overwhelmed as I rush into the world of front-end and back-end development. I feel as if I understand the overarching ideas behind it, but many of the specifics have been very confusing to me. Let me know if there's anything I need to know that I have no clue about yet- thank you for the help, I'm sorry this isn't as specific as it could be.

```
// Tutorial Python code
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", message = "Hello Flask!", contacts = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']);


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

// Corresponding Tutorial HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask Template Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <p>{{ message }}</p>

      <p>{{ contacts }}</p>
      <p>My Contacts:</p>
      <ul>
        {% for contact in contacts %}
        <li>{{ contact }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>

// Second tutorial Python, two @app.route

import sys

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, Response
import random, json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def output():
  return render_template('index.html', name='Joe')

@app.route('/reciever', methods = ['POST'])
def worker():
  data = request.get_json()
  result = ''

  for item in data:
    result += str(item['make']) + '\n'

  return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()

// JavaScript communication first attempt (I was sending them to the second tutorial's Python code)

var sentArray = {"array" : [key, start, finish, holdtime, ud, uu, dd, 1]};
$.post("reciever",sentArray,function(){
});
    event.preventDefault();

// JavaScript communication second attempt

var sentArray = {"array" : [key, start, finish, holdtime, ud, uu, dd, 1]};
fetch('/typing', {
  method: 'POST',

  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }

  body: 
     {"array" : [key, start, finish, holdtime, ud, uu, dd, 1]}
}
});
event.preventDefault();
```

Currently, I receive a 500 error, indicating I'm not handling something properly. I'm not sure what, frankly there are hundreds of ways I could be doing this wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you include the error you are receiving? At a guess though, you might need to change `for item in data:` to `for item in data["array"]:`

Comment: You might also want to break this up into multiple questions. There is a lot to unpack . How do routes work, how do a split out my templates, should I use JSON, how do I make API requests from Javascript etc.

Comment: Thanks @Tim for your response! I moved over to Ajax as Avi Baruch recommended, and have a much more specific question posted now.

Answer (score 0):

try using ajax, it allows you to send post or get requests in the background, I learned ajax with this: [vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJdQxS3ZpNI)

Comment: Thanks for your response- I switched over to AJAX and posted a new question- this advanced me quite a bit, I think I understand much more of what's going on now.